# Ajax -on page load with using a button

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im trying to get ajax to run in a paragraph when the webpage open. I can only get it working if i use a button. Is it possible to have the information from the ajax function to load once the webpage opens?

Here is my code.

```
 <script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = xhttp.status;
      document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = xhttp.statusText;
      document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "home.xml", true);
  xhttp.send(); 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
}
</script>

   <p > <span id="A1"></span></p>
   <button onclick="loadDoc('home.xml')">Get XML data</button>
```

Comment: can you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever function you are invoking, whether it handles ajax or any other calculation, to invoke a function on document load you have to call the function within `window.onload`

```
    function a(){
     ...........
    }

    window.onload = function(){
      a();
    };

   For jquery:

   $(document).ready(functon(){
      a();
   });

    or 

    $(function(){
        a();     
    });
```

Comment: programming confuses me haha. Im new to it all. In my webpage i have a container and in the <p> tag i just wanted to pull the information that i have stored in an xml file by id and place it in that <p> tag of my html page using ajax method

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<body onload="loadDoc('home.xml')">
```

Comment: it worked but not the way i wanted it to work. i have a container and in the <p> tag i just wanted to pull the information that i have stored in an xml file by id and place it in that <p> tag of my html page using ajax method